# Executar um projeto angular 6 do github

Tags: git, github, angular-6

Subi um projeto pro github,acredito que por ser muito grande o arquivo tenha sido "cortado" alguns arquivos,consequentemente quando baixo de novo (utilizando o git clone) o codigo não executa no servidor.

**OPS**:A pasta original(que foi criada) tem aproximadamente 250 mb,já a pasta que foi baixada do github tem 405 kb

**por ser muito grande os projetos angular 6 é possivel subir e baixá-lo de uma forma funcional (executando no servidor)?**

**Motivo:Estou fazendo um curso de Angular 6 e utilizo o github para fazer as alterações e pra ter um código para consulta.**

Comment: Já tentou rodar um `npm install` antes de executar o projeto?

Comment: Lucas, por favor coloque como resposta,executando o comando npm install  solucionou minha dúvida,abraço!

Comment: Feito Felipe ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rode um `npm Install` antes de executar o projeto. O Github não está baixando a pasta node_modules

Uma dica para não aumentar muito o projeto no github é colocar a pasta das bibliotecas do Node.js no arquivo `.gitignore`.